# Selecting data week wise with (week = current timestamp - 7days) and so on in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I am selecting data grouped on the basis of week.

My data contains tickets raised week wise but the week should be current timestamp - 7 days.

So I need to calculate the week not from the start but from the end and then move backwards till the start date i.e. 01-09-2018

Following is the Example of how I need the weeks calculated :

PreviousWeek :      Current Timestamp - 7 days

PreviousWeek - 1:   PreviousWeek -  7 days

PreviousWeek - 2 : (PreviousWeek - 1) - 7 days

and so on.

Complete required data required is :

```
  Week   TicketCount
  11         100
  16         100
  21         100
  26         97
  31         100
   1         77
   6         72
```

I am stuck at this for couple of days any clue to achieve this would be very helpful.

Sample data:

```
  PROBLEMSINCE          STATUS        INITIATOR_DEPARTMENT
  2018-12-20 19:36:34   CLOSED          MWP-PMT-NR
  2018-12-21 12:35:57   CLOSED          MWP-PMT-NR
  2018-12-19 19:00:00   CLOSED          MWP-PMT-NR
 2018-12-19 22:00:00    CLOSED          MWP-PMT-NR
 2018-12-20 21:00:00    CLOSED          MWP-PMT-NR
 2018-12-20 22:00:00    CLOSED         MWP-PMT-NR
 2018-12-13 16:41:18    CLOSE           MWP-PMT-NR
 2017-12-21 10:30:24    CLOSED          MWP-PMT-NR
 2017-12-29 21:22:37    CLOSED          MWP-PMT-NR
 2017-12-29 21:43:42    CLOSED          MWP-PMT-NR
 2018-01-01 13:58:14    CLOSED          MWP-PMT-NR
```

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi, I have attached sample data. I am calculating ticket counts weekwise with problemsince being the ticket creationdate. 
My result should show the ticket count for all tickets raised in current timestamp -7 days and so on backward till 01-09-2018

Comment: Grouped by week

Comment: I have used week() in db2 but it calculates the week from the starting date and in week() the week starts from sunday. 


I hope I have made the query clear.

Comment: To consider: making the week relative will result in a different report results each day. How do you define week 10? Is it because the current date is in week 10?

Comment: @MichealTiefenhacher yes exactly

Comment: I have updated my question properly defining the weeks calculation i need

Answer (score 0):

What's the `01-09-2018` date? It's better to use ISO format. Is this Sep 1-st (`2018-09-01`) or Jan 9-th (`2018-01-09`)?

Your sample data absolutely don't match the result you provided.
Run the following statement as is.

```
with t(week_num, ts_start, ts_end) as (
values (1, current timestamp - 7 days, current timestamp)
  union all
select week_num+1, ts_start - 7 days, ts_end - 7 days
from t
where ts_start > date('2018-09-01')
)
select *
from t
order by week_num
```

Is this expected week numeration?

If not, then update your question with exact expected week numeration, and **matched** sample data and result.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your definition of previous week, you can use one of the following SQLs.

SQL 1:

`select week1 , count(*)
from 
( select  int ( ( days (current date) - days(PROBLEMSINCE) ) / 7 ) as week1 
 from tickets_table
 where PROBLEMSINCE >= '2018-09-01 00:00:00' ) a 
group by week1 
order by 2 desc`

SQL 2:

`select week1 , count(*)
from 
( select  timestampdiff ( 32 , char ( current timestamp - PROBLEMSINCE ) ) as week1 
 from tickets_table
 where PROBLEMSINCE >= '2018-09-01 00:00:00' ) a 
group by week1 
order by 2 desc`